# Using #define in c for equations

Tags: c

Can someone explain to me why the value of y here is 13?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define avg_sum(n) n * (n-1)/2
int main(){
    int y;
    int z = 9;
    y = avg_sum(z+1);
    printf("y=%i\n",y);
}
```

Comment: That's why you always use parentheses around macro arguments when they are part of an arithmetic expression, and parentheses around the macro body as a whole, too, so that `934 / avg_sum(12)` gives you the expected answer too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to answer these sorts of questions is to simply expand the macro in question:

```
y = avg_sum(z+1);

y = z + 1 * (z + 1 - 1) / 2

y = 9 + 1 * (9 + 1 - 1) / 2

y == 13
```

This is why you add parentheses around your macro arguments.

```
#define avg_sum(n) ((n) * ((n)-1)/2)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
avg_sum(9+1) 9+1 * (9+1-1)/2 = 9 + 9/2 = 9+ 4 = 13
```

macros expand each time so 9+1 is not the same as 10, it might be better with safeguarding parenthesis as follows:

```
#define avg_sum(n) ((n) * ((n)-1)/2)
```

but an equivelant **function** will do you much better and be more intuitive and will evaluate arguments only once

`avg_sum(a++)`  will be **`((a++) * ((a++)-1)/2)`** and will increment `a` twice whereas a function will not have these issues since all arguments are evaulated before the function is called

Comment: `static inline int avg_sum(int n) { return (n * (n-1)) / 2; }` works nicely, unless you're stuck with an archaic C90 compiler (eg the default on Windows, MSVC).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in the function version, I'm not sure you need all the parens

Comment: I was not sure either, but better safe than sorry.  Thinking about how things can go wrong if `(n-1)/2` is evaluated before it is multiplied by `n`: suppose `n == 4`.  Then `(n-1)/2` is `1` and `n*1` is `4`; OTOH, `(4 * 3)/2` is `6`. I think the parentheses _do_ matter, if the compiler is allowed to reorder operations, and I think it is.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `5 | * /  % | Multiplication, division, and remainder | left to right`  No reordering allowed - no parens needed

Answer (score 2):

```
y = avg_sum(z+1);
```

expands to `z + 1 * (z+1-1)/2` but it's wrong. Change your macro to

```
#define avg_sum(n) ((n) * ((n)-1)/2)
```

And always parenthesize as well arguments of functional macros as the macro itself . It's an important rule.